# Entity listeners for ADO.NET Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Are there any "after-save", or "before-delete", entity listeners for ADO.NET Entity Framework? If not how could I implement them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These events are available on the Context.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714.aspx

UPDATE 19/12/18

OK so the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20100316181729/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714.aspx) assisted in reminding me of the original content which can now be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges?view=netframework-4.7.2).  Whilst this is updated content it's still relevant for the original question.

Comment: As of 2018-12-19, the link in this answer is dead.

Comment: @IanMcLaird So much for MS respecting the permalink.  Answer updated with later article providing information on the SavingChanges event.

Answer (score 1):

To add support for events like after save, before delete, etc, there are a few options.

**Changes to Entity Values**
If you want to handle the changing of the values in a particular entity, create a new class that extends your entity and extend the OnXXXChanged function, where XXX is the property you wish to monitor.

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    //Before value changes
    partial void OnMyPropertyChanging(int value)
    {
        //Your code here
    }

    //After value changes
    partial void OnMyPropertyChanged()
    {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

**Before Entity Save (Added/Edited/Deleted entities available)**

```
public partial class MyContext
{
    partial void OnContextCreated()
    {
        this.SavingChanges += new EventHandler(OnSavingChanges);
    }

    private void OnSavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        //use ObjectStateManager for entity states
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer - is there something to manage after save?  SavingChanges fires prior to the save.